# Configuring Proxy while installing MS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

How to configure a proxy so that Microsoft visual studio can be downloaded and installed through that proxy .

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/29701/global-proxy-settings-for-windows

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is dated now, but I had a similar issue trying to install Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 behind a firewall.

This is what helped me: Usually you have to install by elevating to admin privileges.  I had to first run Iexplorer.exe as administrator (go to where it's installed, like "C:\Program Files\internet explorer" and right click iexplore.exe and select "Run as administrator"), then open up the settings -> Internet Options -> Connections -> Lan settings.  Update the proxy setting to match what is configured in your Iexplorer under your normal user account.  The installer should now be able to auto-detect proxy setting under the administrator account and download and install correctly.